# Whats the difference between float and volume or are they the same thing?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, trading-volume, chart

Hi I'm still learning and want to know whats the difference between float and volume or are they the same thing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Also is floating stock the same thing as float.

Answer (score 2):

Floating stock is  the number of shares a company has available to trade in the open market.

Volume refers to the number of shares that trade in a time period.